# Detect Cycle In Directed Graph from text file

Tags: c++, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to read in the values from a text file then determine if the graph it represents is a DAG or not. I am wondering what the quickest way to approach this is in terms of time efficiency.

Here is the text file

```
3
2
1,2,
2,3
```

I was thinking of making and adjacency list with the given information and then move from there. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you first build the graph or would you just like to detect a cycle as soon as possible (e.g. without even reading the whole graph)?

Comment: I would Like to detect a cycle and then list starting nodes(nodes with no incoming edges) so I would actually have to build the graph I would assume.

Comment: Not necessarily. In principle you only need to "touch" a set of of edges that comprise a cycle.

Comment: Yes, in the works case you will have to look at the whole graph.

Answer (score 1):

One way, though probably not the fastest one, is to [topologically sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) the graph. The graph has a cycle if and only if the algorithm fails (see [Kahn's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm)).

The running time is `O(|V| + |E|)`, where `|V|` is the number of vertices and `|E|` is the number of edges.

There's a paper by Bender et al. (Robert Tarjan is one of the authors), [A NEW APPROACH TO INCREMENTAL CYCLE DETECTION AND RELATED PROBLEMS](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos528/topsort-1.pdf), which you might want to take a look at.

Another relevant paper is [Incremental Cycle Detection, Topological Ordering, and Strong Component Maintenance](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~sssix/papers/dto-journal.pdf) bu Haeupler et al. (Tarjan is again one of the authors).

Comment: I'll look into the papers tomorrow; I'm now going to bed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may simply traverse the whole graph using [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). It has an overall time complexity of **O(|V| + |E|)**, |V| and |E| being the number of vertices and edges, respectively.

As you traverse the graph using DFS, you will encounter 3 types of vertices:

1. The ones you did not set a foot on, yet.
2. The ones you are currently discovering. (i.e. either itself or its children)
3. The ones you completely explored (i.e. including its descendants)

When implementing DFS, you can keep track of which state each vertex is in at a given time by what is commonly called as *coloring* the vertices. Basically the vertices you haven't started exploring(type 1) would be white, the ones you are in the process of exploring would be gray and the ones you completely discovered(i.e.exhausted) would be black.

On a relevant note, as your DFS runs, it will encounter 4 types of edges based on the type of their source and destination vertices, src and dest, respectively.

1. **Tree Edge:** src is of type 2 and dest is of type 1
2. **Back Edge:** src is of type 2 and dest is of type 2
3. **Forward Edge:** src is of type 2, dest is of type 3 and src is an ancestor of dest
4. **Cross Edge:** src is of type 2, dest is of type 3 and src is **not** an ancestor of dest

Though they are [extensively narrated in graph algorithms sections of most algorithms textbooks](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&lpg=PA178&ots=z8aLOUIT_i&dq=graph%20traversal%20cross%20forward%20tree%20back&pg=PA178#v=onepage&q=graph%20traversal%20cross%20forward%20tree%20back&f=false), forward edges and cross edges are not really relevant to your needs. All you need to consider is to keep track of whether you encounter a **back edge**(i.e. from a gray vertex to another gray vertex) as you traverse the tree.

If you do encounter a back edge, it means that you basically have the capability of going from a vertex *u* to its ancestor *v*. Ancestor feels a bit weird in this context as this is not a tree but a graph. Still, keeping in mind that the directed edges sort of constitute a relationship similar to what a parent and child nodes in a tree has, it may feel more intuitive to grasp the idea. After all, edges of type 1 are called **tree edges** for a reason, right?

To sum up, explore **all** vertices with a depth-first search(i.e. do not give up after you explore one *tree* in your graph) and look for a back edge. If you find one, you have a cycle.